# What is the motivation behind the definition of the truth table of $p\implies q$?

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

The truth table of $p\implies q$ is as follows:

$$\begin{array}{c|c|c}
\boldsymbol{p} & \boldsymbol{q} & \boldsymbol{p\implies q} \\ \hline
\color{green}{\text{T}} & \color{green}{\text{T}} & \color{green}{\text{T}} \\ \hline
\color{green}{\text{T}} & \color{red}{\text{F}} & \color{red}{\text{F}} \\ \hline
\color{red}{\text{F}} & \color{green}{\text{T}} & \color{green}{\text{T}} \\ \hline
\color{red}{\text{F}} & \color{red}{\text{F}} & \color{green}{\text{T}}
\end{array}$$

I know it's just a definition, but I'd like to know the motivation behind it. Here's what I think:

Strictly speaking, the meaning of the proposition $p\implies q$ can be interpreted as **if $\boldsymbol p$ is true, then $\boldsymbol q$ must be also true**. This means that **there's no case in which $\boldsymbol p$ is true and $\boldsymbol q$ is false**. So if $p$ is true and $q$ is false, then $p\implies q$ becomes false and in other cases, it is true.

Am I right?

Comment: Yes, that is how I think of this truth table too. When you state an implication, you're only lying if the conclusion is false while the premise is true.

Comment: In classical propositional logic, when we say, "If it is raining, then it is cloudy," we don't mean rain  causes cloudiness, or that it is always cloudy when it is raining (e.g. sunshowers). We mean only that, at present, it is not both raining and not cloudy. $R \implies C ~~\equiv ~~ \neg (R \land \neg  C)$. If you are familiar with the basic methods of proof, you can find a formal justification of this "definition" starting from what might be called "first principles" at  https://dcproof.wordpress.com/2017/12/28/if-pigs-could-fly/https://dcproof.wordpress.com/2017/12/28/if-pigs-could-fly/

Comment: Yes. Also, related to what you are saying- a big part of why → is important is because of Modus Ponens. Which, says that Given P and P → Q, we can deduce Q

Comment: @MichaelCarey I call it Detachment. It is one of those "first principles" from which the above "definition" can be derived. See https://www.dcproof.com/DeriveImplies.html Each of the rules of inference used there can be thought of as a kind of first principle.